# Roslyn: How to get a reference to Workspace from currently loaded solution?

Tags: roslyn

I am trying to get a reference to currently loaded workspace, without success. As per documentation (part in bold) I should be able to get a reference to it.

> The Workspace APIs are found in the Roslyn.Services namespace, and
>   they are available if you include the following using directive:
>
> using Roslyn.Services;
>
> The workspace you use will typically be provided **directly by the host
>   environment (such as the Visual Studio IDE)**. However, you can work
>   with a workspace outside of a host environment by constructing your
>   own IWorkspace instance.
>
> You can construct a workspace by loading a solution file.
>
> IWorkspace workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution(@"HelloWorld.sln");
>   ISolution solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;

I tried following in unit test but workspace is null.

```
  IWorkspace workspace = Workspace.PrimaryWorkspace;

  ISolution solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;
```

I dont want to load solution, I want to work within currently loaded solution. How is it done? I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Edit:

Tried using switch /rootSuffx Roslyn as suggested in answer and VS throws an error that it is invalid switch. Changed it to /rootSuffix Roslyn, and VS starts but workspace is still null.

Comment: Have you seen this answer http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d37e72dc-d04e-4a60-860f-7487c94b3620/how-to-work-with-workspaceprimaryworkspacecurrentsolution-inside-vspackage?forum=roslyn?

Comment: @nemesv: No, I did not, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described by Dustin Campbell in his answer here: [How to work with Workspace.PrimaryWorkspace.CurrentSolution inside VSPackage](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d37e72dc-d04e-4a60-860f-7487c94b3620/how-to-work-with-workspaceprimaryworkspacecurrentsolution-inside-vspackage)

> The primary workspace inside of Visual Studio is only populated when the Roslyn C# and Visual Basic language services are enabled.

To enable the Roslyn languages services you need to start your VS with the following command:

```
devenv.exe /rootSuffix Roslyn
```

Comment: Yeah I had typo but you need the `Roslyn` part also so the full command is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /rootSuffix Roslyn`

Comment: By the way which unit testing framework and test runner are you using? Are you using the special Roslyn project types?

Comment: NUnit, and yes I have Roslyn at the end.

Comment: @epitka the problem is that the `Workspace.PrimaryWorkspace` get set by the hosting environment. And Visual Studio only sets this when started with `devenv.exe /rootSuffix Roslyn` AND your code is running inside one of the special roslyn porjects like: Code Issue, Code refactoring. So with the CTP the `Workspace.PrimaryWorkspace` will be always null in your unit test project...