# How to get reference to 'Roslyn' Workspace object from IVsSolution?

Tags: roslyn, vspackage

I have a VS Package project from which I need to access Roslyn or Microsoft.CodeAnalysis' Workspace OR Solution object from the loaded [IVsSolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I need to know how I could achieve that ?

I found [this stackoverflow discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576043/roslyn-how-to-get-a-reference-to-workspace-from-currently-loaded-solution) which suggests to use PrimaryWorkspace static property of Workspace class which I can't find in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace

EDIT:
I found out that Microsoft.CodeAnalysis does not have this yet but I downloaded the [older release of Roslyn from Nuget.org](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Roslyn.Services.Common/1.2.20906.2) which has this. But now PrimaryWorkspace Property is giving me NULL :( I am using Isolated Shell.

Comment: We got rid of PrimaryWorkspace since it was too finicky to get initialized. People would often get NULL when they didn't expect it -- just like you are.

Comment: So what is the better alternative ?

Answer (score 3):

The `VisualStudioWorkspace` is exported through MEF. If you are already using MEF in you package, you can just `[Import]` it.

If not, you can `QueryService()` for the `SComponentModel` service and then get the `VisualStudioWorkspace` from that.

Comment: Does package support MEF by default or I should do something?
I wrote [Import] but withing 'Initialize' it's still null.

Answer (score 3):

Within the Initialize() function of your VSPackage, you can use the following:

```
var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel));
var workspace = componentModel.GetService<Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.VisualStudioWorkspace>();
```

I believe you'll also need to add an additional reference to: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll`

As noted by @Vizu, you can now add this via NuGet:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices
```

Comment: I guess that is prerelease on Nuget and I tried downloading, it failed because some dependency was not found on the gallery.

Comment: Yeah I don't think this dependency will be downloaded if you use NuGet. You have to download from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx

Click the purple "Get the Preview" link and download from there.

Comment: NuGet-ing Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices now works fine.