# Roslyn msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync() doesn't opens website projects

Tags: asp.net, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a solution named **RoslynTesting.sln** has 2 projects (*class library and a website*)

```
var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = await msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(@"E:\RoslynTesting\RoslynTesting.sln");
```

`msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync()` gets only the class library project and not the website project.
I could see a message in `msWorkspace.Diagnostics` like **"[Failure] Project file not found: 'E:\RoslynTesting\WebSite1\'"**

Am I missing something or Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll doesn't support Website projects?

**Code to find property declaration and references:**

```
var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create()
var solution = await msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(@"E:\RoslynTesting\RoslynTesting.sln");
var documents = solution.Projects.SelectMany(x => x.Documents).ToList();
var classFile = documents.Where(x => x.FilePath == filePath).FirstOrDefault();
var invocation = await classFile.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
var classNode = invocation.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().Where(x => x.Identifier.Text == className).FirstOrDefault();
var propertyDeclarationNode = classNode.DescendantNodes().OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>().Where(x => x.Identifier.Text == propertyName).FirstOrDefault();           
var model = await classFile.GetSemanticModelAsync();
ISymbol methodSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(propertyDeclarationNode);
var propertyReferences = await SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(methodSymbol, solution);
```

Comment: No, you didn't. `Workspaces` really cannot open the web site without `.proj` file. Check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070323/roslyn-workspace-opensolutionasync-projects-always-empty) from @Jason Malinowski

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria Thank you for your response. So Is there no other way I can access my website project without .proj file?

Comment: What do you mean under "access website"? If you want to access the code from a some file in website you can create compilation and project for it by hand.

Comment: I mean I am trying to find a Property declaration and its references. The property is declared in class library project and has some references in a class under website project (update the code to find property references in question). As workspace cannot open the website proj, I couldn't get the property references in website project.

Comment: You should create a compilation[s] from the website's source and add to it[them] reference on to your class library. When you do that you can append these compilation[s] to your solution creating a new project[s]