# Building "project-less" (no `.csproj`) Web Site Project (WSP) with Roslyn - not supported by MSBuildWorkspace

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, roslyn

We have a Roslyn-based static analysis tool. To build a C# project, either through an `.sln` or `.csproj` file, we use the `MSBuildWorkspace`. In this scenario, everything works well.

Recently, I bumped into an old-style [Web Site Project (WSP)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project/), one that does **not** contain a `.csproj` - pages are compiled on-demand by the server (unless if [precompiled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs)). Not surprisingly, the `MSBuildWorkspace` doesn't support such "project-less" projects, as confirmed by [item 2 in this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070323/roslyn-workspace-opensolutionasync-projects-always-empty).

The difficulty now is to feed the build with the necessary dependencies/assemblies. To deal with such use case, our static analysis tool offers a flag like `-I path/to/dll` so that users can specify directories where to find those DLLs - and I create `MetadataRereferences` for them. While this approach works, it doesn't come with the best user-experience, because the user is not always a developer and might not know all the locations/details.

I'd like to ask whether anyone is aware of an alternative approach to build a project-less Web Site Projects where we could "instruct"/setup Roslyn to mimic the process done by an actual web server to compile the `aspx.cs` files?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not migrate to a web application project in the first place?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I don't think that it's a good *selling approach* that you tell your clients that they need to refactor their project in order to use the tool you provide.