# vsix project context menu visualstudioworkspace

Tags: roslyn, vsix

I am trying to learn more about creating a VSIX project using the Roslyn VisualStudioWorkspace.  I have successfully created a context menu command that appears when right-clicking on a visual studio project.  How do I go about getting a reference to the selected project in code without using ENVDTE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get reference to 'Roslyn' Workspace object from IVsSolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578399/how-to-get-reference-to-roslyn-workspace-object-from-ivssolution)

Answer (score 0):

You can import the visual studio workspace using the MEF

```cs
[Import(typeof(VisualStudioWorkspace))]
public VisualStudioWorkspace ImportedWorkspace { get; set; }
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578399/how-to-get-reference-to-roslyn-workspace-object-from-ivssolution) SO answer for more detail

Comment: No, perhaps the question needs to be re-worded.  I was able to import VisualStudioWorkspace with no problems.  I need to determine which project in a solution was selected when invoking the context menu command.

Comment: i would re-word your question to state exactly what data you have and what you are trying to get. If you have the [IVsHierarchyItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.ivshierarchyitem?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) you can write some code like [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/6d2888693f62b3628c36be3987c53074e6df6f8f/src/VisualStudio/Core/Def/Implementation/HierarchyItemToProjectIdMap.cs#L24) to get the project Id. However you said you don't want to use DTE apis, which would be required to do this.